# Recognize patterns in column, and add them to column in Data frame

Tags: r, regex, text, preprocessor

Got a column with 50 keywords:

```
Keyword1 
Keyword2
Keyword3
KeywordN=50
```

In addition I got a data frame with two columns: Title and Abstract.

```
Title                    Abstract 
Rstudio Keyword1        A interesting program language keyword2  
Python Keyword3         A interesting program keyword3 language
```

I want to get an extra column (let's call it Keywords), where the keyword name will appear IF it is in the Title or Abstract, like this:

```
Title             Abstract                                   Keywords
Rstudio Keyword1 A interesting program language keyword2  Keyword1, keyword2
Python Keyword2  A interesting program keyword3 language  Keyword2, Keyword3
```

The only thing how I could 'solve' this, was by making a binary columns (if a pattern matched). (grepl function), but that was not the desired solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in base `R`:

- This handles punctuation, spaces, end/starts of lines.
- Keywords can contain spaces and some punctuation (but not all)
- keywords in new column keep the case of original keyword vector:

**code**

```
ind  <- sapply(paste0('(^|[ [:punct:]])',tolower(keywords),'($|[ [:punct:]])'),grep,tolower(paste(df$Title,df$Abstract)))
ind[lengths(ind)==0] <- NA # for cases where no keyword is found
ind2 <- do.call(rbind,Map(data.frame,keyword=keywords,i=ind))
ind3 <- aggregate(keyword ~ i,ind2,paste,collapse=', ')
df$keywords[ind3$i] <- ind3$keyword
df$keywords[is.na(df$keywords)] <- "" # replacing NAs with empty strings
#              Title                                Abstract           keywords
# 1 Rstudio Keyword1 A interesting program language keyword2 Keyword1, Keyword2
# 2  Python Keyword2 A interesting program keyword3 language Keyword2, Keyword3
```

**data**

```
keywords <- c("Keyword1", "Keyword2", "Keyword3")

df <- read.table(text="Title                    Abstract 
                 'Rstudio Keyword1'        'A interesting program language keyword2'  
                 'Python Keyword2'         'A interesting program keyword3 language'",h=T,strin=F)
```

Comment: updated as it failed with data from modified question

Comment: > ind2 <- do.call(rbind,Map(data.frame,keyword=keywords1,i=ind))
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: it works fine for me... and it's all base `R`... can someone else replicate the issue ?

Comment: It's not my code in any case, I don't use `keywords1`

Comment: Correct, keywords1 == keywords in my code :-). So that should not be the difference. (Sorry for the confusion)

Comment: Unfortunately not, got this error: 

>Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172429/discussion-between-moody-mudskipper-and-r-overflow).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `strsplit` (also in base R):

```
ls <- strsplit(tolower(paste(df$Title, df$Abstract)), 
                       "(\\s+)|(?!')(?=[[:punct:]])", perl = TRUE)    

df$Keywords <- do.call("rbind", 
               lapply(ls, function(x) paste(unique(x[x %in% tolower(keywords)]), 
               collapse = ", ")))

#             Title                                Abstract           Keywords
#1 Rstudio Keyword1 A interesting program language keyword2 keyword1, keyword2
#2  Python Keyword2 A interesting program keyword3 language keyword2, keyword3
```

#### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(Title = c("Rstudio Keyword1", "Python Keyword2"), 
                 Abstract = c("A interesting program language keyword2",  
                              "A interesting program keyword3 language"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

keywords <- paste0("Keyword", 1:4)
```

Comment: Solution worked. But is there one more possibility, that you get only unique values? 

E.g.: if row one consist out of: keyword1,keyword1 and keyword1, then the result will be: "keyword1", "keyword1", keyword1". Ideally would be one time: "keyword1" (so unique values per row)

Comment: it fails if the keyword happens after a punctuation character

Comment: also fails if the keyword includes a space

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I made an edit for the punctuation issue.

Comment: Thanks, but: 
df$Keywords <- do.call("rbind", 
               lapply(ls, function(x) paste(unique(x[x %in% tolower(keywords))], 
               collapse = ", ")))

Contains some error (I guess with the brackets)

Answer (score 1):

```
cbind(dat,Keywords=do.call(paste,c(sep=",",Map(sub,paste0(".*(",paste(keywords,collapse="|"),").*"),"\\1",dat,TRUE))))
             Title                                Abstract          Keywords
1 Rstudio Keyword1 A interesting program language keyword2 Keyword1,keyword2
2  Python Keyword3 A interesting program keyword3 language Keyword3,keyword3
```

where `keywords=paste0("Keyword",1:3)` and

```
dat=read.table(text="Title                    Abstract 
'Rstudio Keyword1'        'A interesting program language keyword2'  
'Python Keyword3'         'A interesting program keyword3 language'",h=T,strin=F)
```

The line might seem long: Breakdown:

```
a=paste0(".*(",paste(keywords,collapse="|"),").*")
b=do.call(paste,c(sep=",",Map(sub,a,"\\1",dat,TRUE)))
cbind(dat,keywords=b)
             Title                                Abstract          keywords
1 Rstudio Keyword1 A interesting program language keyword2 Keyword1,keyword2
2  Python Keyword3 A interesting program keyword3 language Keyword3,keyword3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Title<-as.character(c("Rstudio Keyword1","Python Keyword3"))
Abstract<-as.character(c("A interesting program language keyword2"," A interesting program keyword3 language"))
example1.data <- data.frame(Title,Abstract)


#loop answer
f<-length(example1.data)
example1.data$Keyword <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(example1.data)){
testA[i]<-regmatches(example1.data$Title[i], regexpr("(Keyword|keyword) ([0-9])", example1.data$Title[i]))
testB[i]<-regmatches(example1.data$Abstract[i], regexpr("(Keyword|keyword)([0-9])", example1.data$Abstract[i]))
example1.data$Keyword[i]<-paste(testA[i],testB[i],  sep=", ")

}
```