# Abstract multiple keywords from text and print in data frame

Tags: r, regex, text, dplyr

I have a data frame (called **all_data**), like this:

```
Title         Text 
Title_1       Very interesting word_1 and also keyword_2
Title_2       hello keyword_1, and keyword_3.
```

I also have a second data frame (called **keywords**), like this:

```
keywords
word_1
word_2
word_3
word_4a word_4b word_4c
```

I want to create **an extra column** in the all_data data frame. In this column, I want to print the relevant keywords IF one of the keywords (from the keywords data frame) occurs in the all_data$Text or all_data$Title column. For example:

```
Title         Text                                               Keywords
Title_1       Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1.   word_1, word_2
Title_2       hello word_1, and word_3.                          word_1, word_3
Title_3       difficult! word_4b, and word_4a also word_4c       word_4a word_4b word_4c
```

! Just print words once in the all_data$Words column, not multiple times. **For me, the harders part is to print a "keyword" like: "keyword_A Keyword_A1 Keyword_A3", which should only appear if all the parts of the keyword are appearing in the relevant text.**

This question is answered here([Recognize patterns in column, and add them to column in Data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677211/recognize-patterns-in-column-and-add-them-to-column-in-data-frame)), where I used DJack his solution:

```
ls <- strsplit(tolower(paste(all_data$Title, all_data$Text)),"(\\s+)|(?!')(?=[[:punct:]])", perl = TRUE)    

all_data$Keywords <- do.call("rbind",lapply(ls,function(x) paste(unique(x[x %in% tolower(keywords)]), collapse = ", ")))
```

**But it fails when multiple keywords are occurring (a keyword like: old grandma, should occur if you have a text like: "Hey your grandma is nice, and very old".**

**UPDATE**

@Nicolas2 helped me with a solution (thanks for that). But unfortunately it fails. Anyone ideas how to solve this? As you can see in the example below, the keyword "feyenoord skin" should for example not appear (since "skin" is not occurring in the text). I only want keywords to appear if they occur in the text (or with multiple keywords, like "Hello World", it would be great if it appears if all words are appearing in the text (so Hello and World). Many thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(Title=c("Title_1","Title_2","Title_3","Title_4","Title_5", "Title_6"), 
                 Text=c("Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1.", 
                        "hello word_1, and word_3.", 
                        "difficult! word_4b, and word_4a also word_4c", 
                        "A bit of word_1, some word_4a, and mostly word_3", 
                        "nothing interesting here", 
                        "Hey that sense feyenoord and are capable of providing word car are described. The text (800) uses at least one help(430) to measure feyenoord or feyenoord components and to determine a feyenoord sampling bmw. The word car is rstudio, at least in part, using the feyenoord sampling bmw. The feyenoord sampling bmw may be rstudio, at least in part, using a feyenoord volume (640) and/or a feyenoord generation bmw, both of which may be python or prerstudio."), 
                 stringsAsFactors=F) 


keywords<-data.frame(Keyword=c("word_1","word_2","word_3","word_4a word_4b word_4c", 
                               "a feyenoord sense", 
                               "feyenoord", "feyenoord feyenoord", "feyenoord skin", "feyenoord collection", 
                               "skin feyenoord", "feyenoord collector", "feyenoord bmw", 
                               "collection feyenoord", "concentration feyenoord", "feyenoord sample",
                               "feyenoord stimulation", "analyte feyenoord", "collect feyenoord", 
                               "feyenoord collect", "pathway feyenoord feyenoord sandboxs", 
                               "feyenoord bmw mouses", "sandbox", "bmw", 
                               "pulse bmw three levels"),stringsAsFactors=F) 

# split the keywords into words, but remember keyword length 
k <- keywords %>% mutate(l=str_split(Keyword," ")) %>% unnest %>% 
  group_by(Keyword) %>% mutate(n=n()) %>% ungroup 
# split the title into words 
# compare with words from keywords 
# keep only possibly multiple, but full matches 
# collate all results and merge back to the original data 
test <- df %>% mutate(l=str_split(Text,"[ .,]")) %>% unnest %>% 
  inner_join(k,by="l") %>% 
  group_by(Title,Keyword) %>% filter(n()%%n==0) %>% 
  distinct(Keyword) %>% ungroup %>% nest(Keyword) %>% 
  rowwise %>% mutate(keywords=paste(data[[1]],collapse=", ")) %>% select(-data) %>% 
  inner_join(df,.,by="Title") 

View(test)
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure i have answered a question exactly like this before. Try the search function harder!

Comment: Couldn't find it in your "answers" on your profile.. neither within the general search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't bother optimizing anything, just did the most straightforward thing:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
setDT(keywords)

keywords[, strsplit(Keyword, ' '), by = Keyword
       ][, c(.SD[, .(row = seq_len(nrow(df)), found = grepl(V1, df$Text)), by = V1],
             N = .N), by = Keyword
       ][, sum(found) == N[1], by = .(Keyword, row)
       ][, paste(Keyword[V1], collapse = ","), by = row]
#   row                                            V1
#1:   1                                 word_1,word_2
#2:   2                                 word_1,word_3
#3:   3                       word_4a word_4b word_4c
#4:   4                                 word_1,word_3
#5:   5                                              
#6:   6 a feyenoord sense,feyenoord,feyenoord bmw,bmw
```

Answer (score 5):

If keywords are made of only one word, so for example "old grandma" could be made of two keywords, "old" and "grandma", what about a solution using a package very nice with text analysis such `tidytext`:

```
library(dplyr)     
library(tidytext)  # text manipulation
```

First, we have to make our data as each word is a row, so we split in this way the all_data and the keywords:

```
all_data_un <- all_data %>% unnest_tokens(word,Text)
    > all_data_un
       Title        word
1    Title_1        very
1.1  Title_1 interesting
1.2  Title_1      word_1
1.3  Title_1         and
1.4  Title_1        also
1.5  Title_1      word_2
1.6  Title_1      word_1
2    Title_2       hello
2.1  Title_2      word_1
2.2  Title_2         and
2.3  Title_2      word_3
3    Title_3   difficult
3.1  Title_3     word_4b
3.2  Title_3         and
3.3  Title_3     word_4a
3.4  Title_3        also
....

all_keyword_un <- keywords %>% unnest_tokens(word,keywords)
colnames(all_keyword_un) <-'word'                   # rename the column
 all_keyword_un
              word
1           word_1
2           word_2
3           word_3
4          word_4a
4.1        word_4b
4.2        word_4c
5                a
5.1      feyenoord
5.2          sense
6        feyenoord
7        feyenoord
7.1      feyenoord
8        feyenoord
8.1           skin
9        feyenoord
9.1     collection
10            skin
10.1     feyenoord
11       feyenoord
11.1     collector
12       feyenoord
12.1           bmw
13      collection
13.1     feyenoord
....
```

As you can see the `unnest_tokens()` removes punctuations and uppercases if necessary.

Now it's possible to filter only the words in the keywords:

```
all_data_un_fi <- all_data_un[all_data_un$word %in% all_keyword_un$word,]
      > all_data_un_fi
       Title      word
1.2  Title_1    word_1
1.5  Title_1    word_2
1.6  Title_1    word_1
2.1  Title_2    word_1
2.3  Title_2    word_3
3.1  Title_3   word_4b
3.3  Title_3   word_4a
3.5  Title_3   word_4c
4    Title_4         a
4.3  Title_4    word_1
4.5  Title_4   word_4a
4.8  Title_4    word_3
6.2  Title_6     sense 
....
```

And the last step: merging the dataset and the keywords found in each sentence:

```
all_data %>%                                      # starting data
left_join(all_data_un_fi) %>%                     # joining without forget any sentence
group_by(Title,Text) %>%                          # group by title and text
summarise(keywords = paste(word, collapse =','))  # put in one cell all the keywords finded


   Joining, by = "Title"
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Title [?]
  Title   Text                                                                                              keywords                    
  <chr>   <chr>                                                                                             <chr>                       
1 Title_1 Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1.                                                  word_1,word_2,word_1        
2 Title_2 hello word_1, and word_3.                                                                         word_1,word_3               
3 Title_3 difficult! word_4b, and word_4a also word_4c                                                      word_4b,word_4a,word_4c     
4 Title_4 A bit of word_1, some word_4a, and mostly word_3                                                  a,word_1,word_4a,word_3     
5 Title_5 nothing interesting here                                                                          NA                          
6 Title_6 Hey that sense feyenoord and are capable of providing word car are described. The text (800) use~ sense,feyenoord,feyenoord,f~
```

---

With keywords made of one or more word, so the keyword of "old grandma" is "old grandma" you can do something like this:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
```

First an empty list:

```
mylist <- list()
```

Then you can populate it with a loop, for each keyword, find the sentences that contains that keyword:

```
for (i in keywords$keywords) {
keyworded <- all_data %>%filter(str_detect(Text, i)) %>% mutate(keyword = i)
  mylist[[i]] <- keyworded}
```

Put it in a data.frame:

```
 df <- do.call("rbind",mylist)%>%data.frame()
```

Then group by each keyword:

```
 df %>% group_by(Title,Text) %>% summarise(keywords = paste(keyword,collapse=','))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Title [?]
  Title   Text                                             keywords
  <chr>   <chr>                                            <chr>                    
1 Title_1 Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1. word_1,word_2            
2 Title_2 hello word_1, and word_3.                        word_1,word_3            
3 Title_4 A bit of word_1, some word_4a, and mostly word_3 word_1,word_3            
4 Title_6 Hey that sense feyenoord and are capable of pro~ feyenoord,bmw,sense feye~
```

Note: the duplicated are removed like in the first sentence, and the `word_4a` is not in because in keywords you have it only in a string with other words.

---

With data (notice I've modified the key adding "sense feyenoord" to test a keyword of two words in the end of `keywords`):

```
   all_data <-  data.frame(Title=c("Title_1","Title_2","Title_3","Title_4","Title_5", "Title_6"), 
                 Text=c("Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1.", 
                        "hello word_1, and word_3.", 
                        "difficult! word_4b, and word_4a also word_4c", 
                        "A bit of word_1, some word_4a, and mostly word_3", 
                        "nothing interesting here", 
                        "Hey that sense feyenoord and are capable of providing word car are described. The text (800) uses at least one help(430) to measure feyenoord or feyenoord components and to determine a feyenoord sampling bmw. The word car is rstudio, at least in part, using the feyenoord sampling bmw. The feyenoord sampling bmw may be rstudio, at least in part, using a feyenoord volume (640) and/or a feyenoord generation bmw, both of which may be python or prerstudio."), 
                 stringsAsFactors=F) 

keywords<-data.frame(keywords = c("word_1","word_2","word_3","word_4a word_4b word_4c", 
                               "a feyenoord sense", 
                               "feyenoord", "feyenoord feyenoord", "feyenoord skin", "feyenoord collection", 
                               "skin feyenoord", "feyenoord collector", "feyenoord bmw", 
                               "collection feyenoord", "concentration feyenoord", "feyenoord sample",
                               "feyenoord stimulation", "analyte feyenoord", "collect feyenoord", 
                               "feyenoord collect", "pathway feyenoord feyenoord sandboxs", 
                               "feyenoord bmw mouses", "sandbox", "bmw", 
                               "pulse bmw three levels","sense feyenoord"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

---

You can also mix the two ways, having both results, and collapse together or create a combination of them.

---

**EDIT:** 
To merge them together, you have many ways, a simple one is this, that also put out uniques:

```
# first we create all the "single" keywords, i e "old grandma" -> "old" and "grandma"
all_keyword_un <- keywords %>% unnest_tokens(word,keywords)
colnames(all_keyword_un) <-'keywords'                   # rename the column

# then you bind them to the full keywords, i.e. "old" "grandma" and "old grandma" together
keywords <- rbind(keywords, all_keyword_un)

# lastly the second way for each keyword
mylist <- list()
for (i in keywords$keywords) {
  keyworded <- all_data %>%filter(str_detect(Text, i)) %>% mutate(keyword = i)
  mylist[[i]] <- keyworded}

df <- do.call("rbind",mylist)%>%data.frame()
df <- df %>% group_by(Title,Text) %>% summarise(keywords = paste(keyword,collapse=','))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Title [?]
  Title   Text                                                                                                            keywords      
  <chr>   <chr>                                                                                                           <chr>         
1 Title_1 Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1.                                                                word_1,word_2~
2 Title_2 hello word_1, and word_3.                                                                                       word_1,word_3~
3 Title_3 difficult! word_4b, and word_4a also word_4c                                                                    word_4a,word_~
4 Title_4 A bit of word_1, some word_4a, and mostly word_3                                                                word_1,word_3~
5 Title_6 Hey that sense feyenoord and are capable of providing word car are described. The text (800) uses at least one~ feyenoord,bmw~
```

Comment: Appreciated s_t! I tried multiple times to get your solution worked on the example data set, but I am facing errors in almost every line. Is that because I am checking it wrongly? Is it working on your computer? Thanks again!!

Comment: You are welcome! There was a typo in the line `colnames(all_keyword_un) <-'word'`, in the first solution: now everything works, let me know if you have any error an where and which one. I've also updated everything to use only the "feyenoord" data.

Comment: This is great! Both methods are working. Thanks a lot, sorry to ask this, but is it also possible to give an example about how to collapse them together? Or is it making two columns (with the keywords) and merge them? And afterwards making everything Unique?

Comment: Edited, added the mix of the two method to have "old grandma" , "old" and "grandma".

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(
   Title=c("Title_1","Title_2","Title_3","Title_4"),
   Text=c("Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1.",
          "hello word_1, and word_3.",                     
          "difficult! word_4b, and word_4a also word_4c",
          "nothing interesting here"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

keywords<-data.frame(Keyword=c("word_1","word_2","word_3","word_4a word_4b word_4c"),stringsAsFactors=F)

df %>% mutate(l=str_split(Text,"[ .,]")) %>% unnest %>%
  inner_join(keywords %>% mutate(l=str_split(Keyword," ")) %>% unnest, by="l") %>%
  select(-Keyword) %>% distinct %>% nest(l)
#    Title                                             Text                      data
#1 Title_1 Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1.            word_1, word_2
#2 Title_2                        hello word_1, and word_3.            word_1, word_3
#3 Title_3     difficult! word_4b, and word_4a also word_4c word_4b, word_4a, word_4c
```

As so, the result is stored in a list. To convert it to a string:

```
df %>% mutate(l=str_split(Text,"[ .,]")) %>% unnest %>%
  inner_join(keywords %>% mutate(l=str_split(Keyword," ")) %>% unnest,by="l") %>%
  select(-Keyword) %>% distinct %>% arrange(l) %>% nest(l) %>%
  rowwise %>% mutate(keywords=paste(data[[1]],collapse=" ")) %>% select(-data)
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Title   Text                                             keywords               
#  <chr>   <chr>                                            <chr>                  
#1 Title_1 Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1. word_1 word_2          
#2 Title_2 hello word_1, and word_3.                        word_1 word_3          
#3 Title_3 difficult! word_4b, and word_4a also word_4c     word_4a word_4b word_4c
```

Upgraded version to remove partial matches when a keyword is several words and treat them as a single entity:

```
df <- data.frame(Title=c("Title_1","Title_2","Title_3","Title_4","Title_5"),
Text=c("Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1.",
       "hello word_1, and word_3.",                     
       "difficult! word_4b, and word_4a also word_4c",
       "A bit of word_1, some word_4a, and mostly word_3",
       "nothing interesting here"),
  stringsAsFactors=F)
  keywords<-data.frame(Keyword=c("word_1","word_2","word_3","word_4a word_4b word_4c"),stringsAsFactors=F)

# split the keywords into words, but remember keyword length
k <- keywords %>% mutate(l=str_split(Keyword," ")) %>% unnest %>%
   group_by(Keyword) %>% mutate(n=n()) %>% ungroup
# split the title into words
# compare with words from keywords
# keep only possibly multiple, but full matches
# collate all results and merge back to the original data
df %>% mutate(l=str_split(Text,"[ .,]")) %>% unnest %>%
   inner_join(k,by="l") %>%
   group_by(Title,Keyword) %>% filter(n()%%n==0) %>%
   distinct(Keyword) %>% ungroup %>% nest(Keyword) %>%
   rowwise %>% mutate(keywords=paste(data[[1]],collapse=", ")) %>% select(-data) %>%
   inner_join(df,.,by="Title")
#    Title                                             Text                keywords
#1 Title_1 Very interesting word_1 and also word_2, word_1.          word_1, word_2
#2 Title_2                        hello word_1, and word_3.          word_1, word_3
#3 Title_3     difficult! word_4b, and word_4a also word_4c word_4a word_4b word_4c
#4 Title_4    A bit word_1, some word_4a, and mostly word_3          word_1, word_3
```

Comment: Great. But if you assign your code to a data frame (like this: foo <- df %>%.....) and then View(foo), you will see that the column data is not correct (represented as: list(l = c("word_1", "word_2")) ). 

In addition, I see that word_4b, word_4a and word_4c are represented as separate words. Is it possible to print it like: word_4a word4_b word 4_c (as one keyword)? 

Again: thank you!

Comment: print it like the original words, as in the keywords data frame :-) so: "word_4a word_4b word_4c"

Comment: @R overflow I upgraded my answer. Did you mena that the commas separating word_1 and word_2 were relevant?

Comment: This is great! Yes, now the answer could be something like: word_1 word_4a word_4b word_4c. What I really looking for was almost that, but separated with a comma (like: word_1, word_4a word_4b word_4c). As you might see: keywords word_4a word_4b word_4c are not separated with a comma. Really appriciated, Nicolas2!

Comment: @R overflow Nothing is impossible, it will just complicate the code. What are you expecting for a sentence like : "A bit word_1, some word_4a, and mostly word_3"?

Comment: Amazing! I expect then: word_1,  word_3

Comment: @R overflow Answer upgraded with that new specification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180796/discussion-between-nicolas2-and-r-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

```
Title <- c("A","B","C","A","A","B","A","A","B","C")
Text <- c("A",11,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,"hi")
df <- data.frame(Title,Text, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

keywords <- c("A","B","hi")
keys <- data.frame(keywords,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It's a bit of a long chain of logic, it's gonna be hard to read. But it's literally one mutate, clean and fast.

```
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)
df %>% mutate(Keywords = paste(str_c(keys$keywords[which(keys$keywords %in% 
df$Title)],collapse = ","),str_c(keys$keywords[which(!keywords %in% 
df$Title)] 
[which(keywords[which(!keywords %in% df$Title)] %in% df$Text)], 
collapse=","), 
sep=",")) -> df
```

Let me break it down a bit, within the paste we have two terms, first is

```
str_c(keys$keywords[which(keys$keywords %in% df$Title)],collapse = ",")
```

Which finds keywords in `$Title` column and needs `str_c` to concatenate the found keywords into one string to avoid messy repetitions due to a non-concatenated result being a data-frame rather than a string. The next term is:

```
str_c(keys$keywords[which(!keywords %in% df$Title)][which(keywords[which(!keywords 
%in% df$Title)] %in% df$Words)], collapse=",")
```

Which looks awful, but is calling for the keywords that weren't in `$Title`, which are in `$Text`. This rather long bit of logic is needed so that we don't repeat the keywords that we saw in `$Title`. For the same reasons we should use `str_c` to make a string output. Then the paste of the two strings gives us your desired output. Tinkering with the `collapse=" ,"` and `sep = " ,"` can add spaces if you want.